# Session between different PHP script and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

In my different script (not using Codeigniter on this, but its on the same domain) I'm setting my session data this way:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = 'test';
```

How comes it does works in that separated file but it doesn't in the Codeigniter session?

When I'll `var_dump( $this->session->all_userdata() );` in any Codeigniter controller it doesn't show my `'something'` session data.

Whats wrong? Can it be done this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter manages its own sessions, and has a few different storage methods ( it doesn't necessarily use php's native session storage as a backend).

You should still be able to access your `something` variable in codeigniter by doing

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

If you're not worried about modifying the CI core, you can modify the session library to pull in data from $_SESSION.

A cleaner solution would be to write a hook that merges the native CI sessions with the default PHP $_SESSION superglobal.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried to `var_dump` the `$_SESSION` but it does throw the following error message: `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: Nevermind, forgot about the `session_start();` there... thank you.